# Measure Product Theorem: may non-$\sigma$-finiteness result unique product?

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $i\in\{1,2\}$. The Measure Product Theorem states that, given the measure spaces $(X_i,\Sigma_i,\mu_i)$, there is at least one product measure $\pi$ such that $\pi(A_1\times A_2)=\mu_1(A_1)\;\mu_2(A_2)$, for $A_i\in\Sigma_i$.

It also states that if the $\mu_i$'s are $\sigma$-finite, then $\pi$ is unique.

I'd like an example of a non-$\sigma$-finite pair of measures from which, nevertheless, we only obtain one product, thus showing "if" cannot be "iff" on the paragraph above.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Hmmm, you're right. I had actually found that question before, but not read it. I thought it was a "counter-counter-example", but it's about a counter. I will edit my question and ask about a double counter instead.

Comment: @All: This is **no longer** a duplicate.

Comment: @t.b. You're right, I voted to close, but now I can't remove my vote.

Comment: @Davide: You can't (I voted to close, too, before the question was changed). You could remove your "possible duplicate" comment, though (in the hope that people no longer vote for closure).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trivial example: $X = \{x\}$ has one point, $\mu(\{x\}) = \infty$, $X_1 = X_2 = X$, and $\mu_1 = \mu_2 = \mu$.  Not $\sigma$-finite, but the unique product measure is $\lambda(\{(x,x)\}) = \infty$.

Answer (score 5):

Take an uncountable set $X$ with counting measure defined on the power set and consider $X \times X$. Then the usual product measure and the complete locally determined product measure coincide with counting measure on the product and we conclude by the result that any measure $\lambda$ on the product $\sigma$-algebra satisfying $\lambda(A \times B) = \mu(A) \nu(B)$ for all sets $A$ and $B$ of finite measure must lie between the complete locally determined product and the usual product, as was explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70888/uniqueness-of-product-measure-non-sigma-finite-case).