# Is $\sigma$-finiteness necessary for the existence and uniqueness of product measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, product-space

Let $(X,\mathfrak{B}_X,\mu_X)$ and $(Y,\mathfrak{B}_Y,\mu_Y)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. Then there exists a unique measure $\mu_X\times\mu_Y$ on $\mathfrak{B}_X\times\mathfrak{B}_Y$ that obeys $\mu_X\times\mu_Y(E\times F)=\mu_X(E)\times\mu_Y(F)$ whenever $E\in \mathfrak{B}_X$ and $F\in \mathfrak{B}_Y$.

That is the existence and uniqueness of product measure.

I want to ask if I remove condition"$\sigma$-finite", is the conclusion still correct? If not, please give a counterexample.

Comment: So there always exists such a measure on the product space. However if the space is not $\sigma$-finite, then there [may](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70888/uniqueness-of-product-measure-non-sigma-finite-case) or [may not](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84008/measure-product-theorem-may-non-sigma-finiteness-result-unique-product) be more than one.

Comment: I understand.Thank you very much!!!