# Product of Lebesgue and counting measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathbb R$ be endowed with the standard Euclidean topology and let $\widetilde {\mathbb R}$ denote the line endowed with the *discrete* topology. Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ denote the Lebesgue and counting measures on these two spaces, respectively.

Suppose that $E\in\mathscr B_{\mathbb R\times\widetilde{\mathbb R}}$ is a Borel-measurable set on the product space. For each $y\in\widetilde{\mathbb R}$, define $$E^y\equiv\{x\in\mathbb R\,|\,(x,y)\in E\}.$$ Assume also that $$G\equiv\{y\in\widetilde{\mathbb R}\,|\,\mu(E^y)>0\}$$
is a countable set and also that $$\sum_{y\in G}\mu(E^y)<\infty.$$ I am trying to prove the following: $$\boxed{(\mu\times\nu)(E)=\sum_{y\in G}\mu(E^y),}\tag{*}$$
where $$(\mu\times\nu)(E)\equiv\inf\left\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_k)\cdot \nu(B_k)\,\Bigg|\,E\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\times B_k,\,A_k\in\mathscr B_{\mathbb R},\,B_k\subseteq\widetilde{\mathbb R}\,\forall k\right\}\tag{**}$$
is the product measure on $\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}\otimes\mathscr B_{\widetilde{\mathbb R}}=\mathscr B_{\mathbb R\times\widetilde{\mathbb R}}$. (Remark: I have already proved that these latter two $\sigma$-algebras coincide and also that $E^y\in\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}$ for any $y\in\widetilde{\mathbb R}$).

---

Attempts:

- It is not difficult to show that $(\mu\times\nu)(E)\geq\sum_{y\in G}\mu(E^y)$, given that $$E=\bigcup_{y\in\widetilde{\mathbb R}}E^y\times\{y\}\tag{***}$$
  and this union is disjoint.
- As for the other direction, note that $\{E^y\times\{y\}\}_{y\in\widetilde{\mathbb R}}$ cover $E$ according to $(***)$, so one could use the infimum property of the product measure $\mu\times\nu$ in $(**)$ to establish the desired inequality. The problem is that this union is *uncountable* (even though only countably many $y\in\widetilde{\mathbb R}$ have $m(E^y)>0$), so it may not be a suitable cover based on which $(**)$ could be made use of.

---

Any hints/thoughts are appreciated.

---

**UPDATE #1:** Possible counterexample: Let $E\equiv\{(x,x)\,|\,x\in[0,1]\}$. Clearly, $E^y=\{y\}$ if $y\in[0,1]$ and $\varnothing$ otherwise. It is clear also that $E\in\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}\otimes\mathscr B_{\widetilde{\mathbb R}}$. It follows that $G=\varnothing$ and the right-hand side of $(*)$ vanishes. However, it is [well-known](http://math.ucr.edu/~edwardb/Graduate%20Classes/Math%20209A/Homework%203.pdf) that $(\mu\times\nu)(E)=\infty$ *whenever $\widetilde{\mathbb R}$ is endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the counting measure*. In the present setting, though, $\widetilde{\mathbb R}$ is endowed with the *discrete topology* and the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra $2^{\widetilde{\mathbb R}}$! Hence, there *may* still be some hope that the left-hand side of $(*)$ vanishes, too; to do this, one must cover $E$ with a countable union of rectangles of the form $(A_k,B_k)\in\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}\times 2^{\widetilde{\mathbb R}}$ the measures of whose products are small. To achieve the desired result, at least some of $B_k$'s must be non-Borel-measurable (say, cleverly chosen Vitali sets), in order to avoid the conclusion that $(\mu\times\nu)(E)=\infty$. Is such a choice of non-Borel sets possible, or is it the case that $(\mu\times\nu)(E)=\infty$ with the discrete topology, too?

---

**UPDATE #2:** The result *should* be true. According to [Bogachev (2007)](http://books.google.com/books?id=hJ_BngEACAAJ&dq=bogachev+measure&hl=hu&sa=X&ei=ciLOU_S6D8qMyAS874KYCw&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAw) (Example 7.14.65, pp. 154–155), the measure $$E\mapsto\sum_{y\in\widetilde{\mathbb R}}\mu\left(E^y\right)$$ coincides with $(\mu\times\nu)$, as defined above in $(*)$, but this result is mentioned only; no proof is provided. If this is true, then the possible counterexample is obviated, too, and the diagonal of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ should have a vanishing product measure.

Comment: The product measure $\mu\times \nu$ on $\mathcal{L}([0,1]) \times 2^{[0,1]}$ is not unique. As you said in Update2, $E\mapsto \sum \mu(E^y)$ is a product measure, which means it satisfies property $(**)$, but you can not really show it equals $``\mu\times \nu"$. Your Update1 is correct as well, that is the classic example showing that the product measure is not unique when one of the measures is not $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: @Xiao Note that the whole question is _whether_ the measure $E\mapsto\sum_{y\in\widetilde{\mathbb R}}\mu(E^y)$ satisfies property $(**)$. If it does, then it must be equal to $\mu\times\nu$, because $(**)$ is the _definition_ of the product measure $\mu\times\nu$. By “the” product measure, I mean the Carathéodory construction, yielding $(**)$. But your point on the product measure not being the unique extension of products of rectangles to a measure on the product $\sigma$-algebra—due to the non-$\sigma$-finiteness of $\nu$—is very useful, thank you!

Comment: Yes, never mind, I misread your $**$. I will take a look at this again.

Comment: The result is NOT true. The counter-example is exactly the one presented in **UPDATE #1**  and the prove it works can be found here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176746/product-of-lebesgue-and-counting-measures

Comment: Regarding **UPDATE #2**: When, in 7.14.65, Bogachev writes "$\mu$ is the product
of the counting measure on $\Omega$ and Lebesgue measure", he does not mean that $\mu$ is the product measure. He is simply translating to words the formula 
$$ \mu(B)\equiv\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}\lambda(B_{\omega})$$
I agree that his choice of words may be misleading. Please, note that goal of 7.14.65 is just to show an example of an infinite Radon measure (as defined in 7.14.64) on an locally compact space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but the following seems to suffice.

By the definition of the product measure (or Tonelli's Theorem if you prefer),
$$
(\mu\times\nu)(E)=\int 1_Ed(\mu\times\nu)=\int \left(\int 1_E(x,y)d\mu(x) \right) d\nu(y).
$$
But $1_E(x,y)=1_{E^y}(x)$, so
$$
\int \left(\int 1_E(x,y)d\mu(x) \right) d\nu(y)=\int \mu(E^y)d\nu(y)=\sum_{y}\mu(E^y).
$$
Clearly
$$
\sum_{y}\mu(E^y)=\sum_{y\in G}\mu(E^y),
$$
which was what you wanted.

EDIT: My measure theory, as you may have already noticed, is a bit rusty. Hopefully, there are not too many errors in the following. I follow the notation of 'Real Analysis and Probability' by Dudley. From page 134, the set $\mathcal R$ of rectangles $A\times B$ with $A,B$ measurable is a semi-ring, and $\rho(A\times B)=\mu(A)\nu(B)$ is countably additive on $\mathcal R$. Then $\rho$ can be extended uniquely to a countably additive function (still denoted $\rho$) on the algebra $\mathcal A$ generated by $\mathcal R$. The product measure, $\mu\times\nu$, you have defined, as far as I can tell, is then the outer measure (Caratheodory extension) generated by this $\rho$. Another extension would be $m(E)=\sum_{y}\mu(E^y)$.

Observation: Any extension $\alpha$ of $\rho$ satisfies $m\leq\alpha\leq (\mu\times\nu)$: Let $E\subset\bigcup_{k}A_k\times B_k$. Then
$$
\alpha(E)\leq \sum_k \alpha(A_k\times B_k)=\sum_k \mu(A_k)\nu(B_k).
$$
Taking the infimum yeilds $\alpha(E)\leq(\mu\times\nu)(E)$. As for the other inequality, observe that if $F$ is a finite set such that $E\supset\bigcup_{y\in F}E^y\times \{y\}$, then
$$
\alpha(E)\geq \sum_{y\in F} \alpha(E^y\times\{y\})=\sum_{y\in F} \mu(E^y).
$$
Taking the supremum over finite sets $F$ yeilds $\alpha(E)\geq m(E)$. As a consequence, $m=(\mu\times\nu)$ if and only if the product measure is unique (which may already indicate that the assertion may not hold in general).

If we use your example from update 1, $m(E)=0$ but $(\mu\times\nu)(E)=\infty$. In this relation, see the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70888/uniqueness-of-product-measure-non-sigma-finite-case). I will now argue that $(\mu\times\nu)(E)=\infty$ indeed holds. Given any $A_k,B_k$ such that $E\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\times B_k$, consider the family
$$
\{A_k\times B_k\;|\mu(A_k)>0\;\}.
$$
This family must cover uncountably many of the points of $E$ (since $\mu(\bigcup A_k)\leq\sum\mu(A_k)=0$ when the union/sum ranges over those $k$ such that $\mu(A_k)=0$, and the complement of a Lebesgue-measure-zero set in [0,1] is uncountable). It follows that there is some $k$ such that $\mu(A_k)>0$ and $B_k$ is uncountable, which in particular implies $\nu(B_k)=\infty$. But then
$$
\sum_k \mu(A_k)\nu(B_k)=\infty.
$$

EDIT: Since counting measure is strictly localizable and Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-finite, Theorem 252B of 'Measure Theory Vol 2' by Fremlin applies. Perhaps Bogachev is talking about the c.l.d. product measure (in the words of Fremlin) when he says 'the' product measure.

EDIT: Using Lemma 417B from Fremlin Vol IV, one sees also that we can define an extension $\alpha$ of $\rho$ by
$$\alpha(E)=∫ν(E_x)dμ(x).$$
Here, $x\mapsto ν(E_x)$ is measurable by the lemma. As for $\sigma$-additivity, note that if $E_n$ are disjoint sets, then $(E_n)_x$ are disjoint sets as well. Using that $m\leq\alpha\leq (\mu\times\nu)$, we see again that $m\neq (\mu\times\nu)$, by considering your example from update 1.

Comment: Tonelli is not guaranteed to work here, because the counting measure is not $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: What do you mean by the product measure in that case?

Comment: It's the standard definition of product measures, as given in $(**)$ above.

Comment: I see. It seems to me that, by that definition, $F=\bigcup_{y\notin G}E^y\times\{y\}$ should be a zero-set. Then $E=F\cup\bigcup_{y\in G} E^y\times\{y\}$ is a countable disjoint union.

Comment: The issue with this is that while $E^y\times\{y\}$ is indeed a zero set for any $y\in G^c$, the frustrating fact is that $G^c$ is uncountable! It's not guaranteed that the uncountable union of zero sets is zero (in general—whether this is the case here is the question).

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. If the assertion does not hold, though, it means that Bogachev's result is wrong, doesn't it? I'm surprised because I thought of it as an authoritative resource in measure theory. Perhaps Bogachev means _a_ product measure and not “_the_” product measure, as I defined it?

Comment: It looks like an error to me.

Comment: Thank you, your input has been very helpful. Now I see that the counterexample holds up even with the discrete $\sigma$-algebra.