# If $\mu$ is a finite measure and $\nu$ is a signed measure, can we extend the inequality $|\nu|\le C\mu$ from a generator to the whole σ-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, signed-measures

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a finite measure space
- $\mathcal E$ be a semiring with $\sigma(\mathcal E)=\mathcal A$
- $\nu$ be a signed measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ with $$|\nu(A)|\le C\mu(A)\;\;\;\text{for all }A\in\mathcal E\tag1$$ for some $C\ge0$

> Are we able to show that $(1)$ holds for all $A\in\mathcal A$?

If $|\nu|$ (the composition of the absolute value function and $\nu$; not to be confused with the total variation of $\nu$) would be a measure, then $$\mathcal E\ni A\mapsto C\mu(A)-|\nu(A)|\tag2$$ would be a (nonnegative) pre-measure on $\mathcal E$ and hence admit a unique extension to a (nonnegative) measure on $\mathcal A$. The desired claim would follow immediately.

However, $|\nu|$ should fail to be additive and hence this argumentation is not possible. So, what can we do?

Comment: Are you still interested in this question?  Is my answer acceptable to you?  There's actually a small typo there, which I would be happy to address if you like.

Comment: @fourierwho Yes, I'm still interested, but I didn't found the time to go through your answer. Which typo do you mean?

Comment: @oxbadf00d, never mind, I fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that $\Omega = \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_{n}$, where $\{A_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathscr{E}$.  Note that this assumption is necessary for the "and hence admit a unique extension" result the OP is quoting.  See, for example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70888/uniqueness-of-product-measure-non-sigma-finite-case) post.

In what follows, I will assume that $\{A_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is pairwise disjoint.  To see this is no restriction, observe that if $A_{n} \cap A_{m} \neq \phi$, then observe that $A_{n} \cap A_{m} \in \mathscr{E}$ and $A_{m} \setminus A_{n}$ is a disjoint union of finitely many sets in $\mathscr{E}$.  Thus, cutting up the $\{A_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ as required, we can obtain a sequence $\{\tilde{A}_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathscr{E}$ that is pairwise disjoint and covers $\Omega$.

Define a collection $\mathscr{B}$ of subsets of $\Omega$ by 
$$\mathscr{B} = \{A \in \mathcal{A} \, \mid \, |\nu(A)| \leq C \mu(A) \, \, \text{and} \, \, |\nu(\Omega \setminus A)| \leq C \mu(\Omega \setminus A)\}.$$  $\mathscr{B}$ is a $\lambda$-system.  Indeed, $\Omega \in \mathscr{B}$ since
$$\left|\nu \left(\bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_{n} \right) \right| \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} |\nu(A_{n})| \leq C \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mu(A_{n}) = C \mu(\Omega).$$
Notice that this same reasoning implies that if $\{C_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathscr{B}$ is pairwise disjoint, then $\bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} C_{n} \in \mathscr{B}$.  Finally, by construction, $A \in \mathscr{B}$ implies $\Omega \setminus A \in \mathscr{B}$.

Since $\mathscr{E}$ is a semi-ring, it is a $\pi$-system.  Suppose $A \in \mathscr{E}$.  Since $\mathscr{E}$ is a semi-ring, if $A \in \mathscr{E}$ and $L \in \mathbb{N}$, then there exist pairwise disjoint sets $C_{1},C_{2},\dots,C_{N} \in \mathscr{E}$ such that $\A_{L} \setminus A = C_{1} \cup \dots \cup C_{N}$.  Therefore,
$$|\nu(A_{L} \setminus A)| \leq |\nu(C_{1})| + \dots + |\nu(C_{N})| \leq C \mu(A_{L} \setminus A).$$
Summing over $L$ (and appealing to the fact that $\{A_{L}\}_{L \in \mathbb{N}}$ is disjoint), we obtain
$$|\nu(\Omega \setminus A)| \leq \sum_{L = 1}^{\infty} |\nu(A_{L} \setminus A)| \leq C \sum_{L  = 1}^{\infty} \mu(A_{L} \setminus A) = C \mu(\Omega \setminus A).$$
Since $|\nu(A)| \leq C \mu(A)$ by hypothesis, this completes the proof that $A \in \mathscr{B}$.  Therefore, $\mathscr{E} \subseteq \mathscr{B}$.

$\mathscr{E}$ is a $\pi$-system contained in the $\lambda$-system $\mathscr{B}$.  Therefore, by Dynkin's Theorem, $\mathcal{A} = \sigma(\mathscr{E}) \subseteq \mathscr{B}$.

Comment: $\nu$ is not defined on the $\mathcal A$ so $\mathcal B$ is not defined. I have posted a solution below.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The question explicitly states that $\nu$ is defined on $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: I am  sorry, I was misled by the talk of extensions in the argument by the proposer. Anyway, I have proved that if $\nu$ is given on the semiring and if it satisfies the inequality in the statement then it can be uniquely extended and  the  inequality continues to hold.

Comment: I believe we need to assume that $\Omega \in \mathcal{E}$ in order to apply the monotone class theorem, and this need not be the case for a semiring.

Comment: You caught me.  I figured I should probably be using $\pi$-$\lambda$ instead of monotone class...  Notice that we don't need to assume $\mathscr{E}$ is a semi-algebra, but I don't know how to get around assuming that $\mathscr{E}$ contains a sequence that covers $\Omega$.

Answer (score 0):

By the basic approximation result of measure theory (ref. Halmos), for any $A \in \mathcal A$ we can find a sequence $\{A_n\}$ in the semiring such that $\mu (A \Delta A_n)$ tends to 0. Now $|\nu (A_n)-\nu (A_m)| =|\nu (A_n \setminus A_m)-  \nu (A_m \setminus A_n)| \leq \mu (A_n \Delta A_m)$ which tends to 0. The Cauchy sequence $\{ \nu (A_n)\}$ is convergent and we can define $\nu (A)$ as its limit. A straight-forward argument shows that $\nu$ is well-defined and additive on $\mathcal A$. Now 1) holds for all A in $\mathcal A$ which also makes teh extension countable additive.

Comment: Are you assuming $\nu$ is an additive function on $\mathcal{A}$?  Otherwise, how do you get $|\nu(A_{n}) - \nu(A_{m})| = |\nu(A_{n} \setminus A_{m}) - \nu(A_{m} \setminus A_{n})|$?

Comment: Aren't signed measures supposed to be additive?

Comment: Yes.  What are your assumptions?  You wrote "A straightforward argument shows $\nu$ is well-defined and additive on $\mathcal{A}$" and "... which also makes the extension countably additive."  This prompted my comment.