# Counterexample For Measure Equivalence

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

> **Question.** If $\mu_1$,$\mu_2$ measures on the space $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}^n)$, where $\mathcal{B}^n$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and
> $$\mu_1\left(\prod_{i=1}^n (x_i, y_i]\right) = \mu_2\left(\prod_{i=1}^n (x_i, y_i]\right) \tag{1},$$
> with $x_i,y_i \in \mathbb{R}$, then provide a counterexample to show that $\mu_1 \neq \mu_2$.

**So far.** There's a lemma that I'm aware of that deals with this where if for (1) we instead have, $\mu_1(\cdot) = \mu_2(\cdot) < \infty$, then $\mu_1 = \mu_2$. Hence, my idea is that it breaks down when we don't enforce finiteness. However, I'm struggling coming up with a counterexample of this specifically. Any ideas?

Comment: This help? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/267841/252983

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\#$ be the counting measure on the space $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}^n)$, where $\mathcal{B}^n$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Just take $\mu_1=  \#$ and $\mu_2= 2 \cdot \#$.

It is clear that $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$ are measures on the space $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}^n)$,
$$\mu_1\left(\prod_{i=1}^n (x_i, y_i]\right) = \mu_2\left(\prod_{i=1}^n (x_i, y_i]\right) = +\infty$$
if, for all $i\in\{1, \cdots n\}$, $x_i < y_i \in \mathbb{R}$, and
$$\mu_1\left(\prod_{i=1}^n (x_i, y_i]\right) = \mu_2\left(\prod_{i=1}^n (x_i, y_i]\right) = 0$$
if, there is an $i\in\{1, \cdots n\}$ such that $x_i = y_i \in \mathbb{R}$. **But** $\mu_1 \neq \mu_2$.