# Measures on the product space and the Fubini theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X_i, M_i, \mu_i), i=1,2$ be two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. One can define a product measure $\mu_1\times \mu_2$ on $X_1 \times X_2$ by defining a pre-measure on the rectangles. The $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu_1\times \mu_2$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by those rectangles (denoted this by $M_1 \times M_2$).

**Question:**

1. Why not define the $\sigma$-algebra $M$ of $\mu_1\times \mu_2$ to be the $\sigma$-algebra induced by the exterior measure (which is induced by the pre-measure)? We certainly have $M_1 \times M_2 \subset M$. But do we have $\overline{M_1 \times M_2} = M$ (the $\overline{M_1 \times M_2}$ is the completion of $M_1 \times M_2$)? I can show that for the Lebesgue measure, this is the case.
2. If we use $M$ as the $\sigma$-algebra for the product measure, then does the Fubini theorem hold?

Comment: Does this helps you?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#For_complete_measures

Comment: Thank you, I found the following post is relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70888/uniqueness-of-product-measure-non-sigma-finite-case

Comment: Moreover, Fremlin's book Measure Theory, Vol 5, 251K, page 201 confirms that the two measures are the same.