# Why is Uniqueness of Product Measure not automatic?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure) the product measure $\mu_1\times\mu_2$ of two measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ is unique if $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are $\sigma$-finite.

I wonder how the requirement that $(\mu_1\times\mu_2)(E_1\times E_2)=\mu_1(E_1)\times\mu_2(E_2)$ is insufficient as it appears at first sight to define $\mu_1\times\mu_2$ on all inputs. This must be incorrect and I saw somewhere that this requirement is only a premeasure (I suppose a partially defined measure).
Can someone maybe give a hint on which kinds of inputs are not necessarily defined by this requirement?

Also, in my setting, I work with products of probability measures: these are guaranteed to be sigma-finite, right?

Comment: Probability measures are finite, and thus sigma finite.

Comment: The rest of your question is a soft duplicate, at least in the sense that you figure out what inputs fail while building a counterexample: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70888/269764

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen. I even had that link open but I still do not get it. It must be that the requirement only partially determines the resulting measure. Is $\Sigma_1\otimes\Sigma_2=\Sigma_1\times\Sigma_2$? I am not sure what the formulation on the wikipedia site really means. I see that the counterexample uses a diagonal i.e. not a rectangle but I am not sure if that means that $\Sigma_1\otimes\Sigma_2=2^{X_1\times X_2}$ or something else... (which would be strange as $\Sigma_1\otimes\Sigma_2$ would then not depend on $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$?)

Comment: Not every subset of the plane is a product of two subsets of the line, think of a triangle for example.

Comment: Ok, so this seems to imply that $\Sigma_1\otimes\Sigma_2=2^{X_1\times X_2}$. But the wikipedia page says that $\Sigma_1\otimes\Sigma_2$ is 'generated by' subsets of pairs from $\Sigma_1\times\Sigma_2$. It is still unclear to me how this _generation_ happens. I would just like to see the exact formal definition (as trivial as it may seem).

Comment: @RonnieMarksch the exact formal definition of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a family of sets is the smallest (equivalently, "intersection of every") $\sigma$-algebra containing that family.  (Incidentally, this is NOT generally $2^{X_1\times X_2}$)

Comment: There is formal definition for the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a family of sets in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra).